# How to bind Blaze templates with Meteor data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have code with some calculations:

```
 Template.smartoptimizer.onCreated(function () {
    this.currentSelector = new ReactiveVar({});
    this.ready = new ReactiveVar(false);
    this.length = new ReactiveVar(31.8);
    this.width = new ReactiveVar(48.3);
    this.height = new ReactiveVar(3.38);
    this.area = new ReactiveVar((31.8 + 2*0.6)*(48.3 + 2*0.6));

    this.workingSpace = new ReactiveVar(0.60);
    this.slopeAngle = new ReactiveVar('1:1');

    this.excSloped = function() {
        let data = {};
        data.areaExPit = (this.length + 2*this.workingSpace)*(this.width + 2*this.workingSpace);
        data.areaTerrain = (this.length + 2*this.workingSpace + 2*this.width)*(this.width + 2*this.workingSpace + 2*this.width);
        data.volumePrism = this.height/3 * (data.areaExPit + Math.sqrt(data.excSloped*data.areaTerrain) + data.areaTerrain);
        data.volumeBackf = data.volumePrism - (this.height*this.length*this.width);
        return data;
    };

    this.excVertical = function() {
        let data = {};
        data.areaExPit = (this.length + 2*this.workingSpace)*(this.width + 2*this.workingSpace);
        data.areaTerrain = (this.length + 2*this.workingSpace)*(this.width + 2*this.workingSpace);
        data.volumePrism = ((data.areaExPit*data.areaTerrain) / 2) * 5;
        data.volumeBackf = data.volumePrism - (this.height*this.length*this.width);
        data.wallArea = this.height*(this.length + 2*this.workingSpace) + 2*(this.width + 2*this.workingSpace);
        return data;
    };
     });
```

Also I have `calculationsData` helper which have an object with results of the calculations.
So, i need to put this in my Blaze template and I dont know how.

```
<template name="smartoptimizer">
    <div class="row">
        {{#with calculationsData}}
            <div class="col s4">
                        <h4>excavation sloped</h4>
                        <table class="bordered striped calculations-table" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>area excavation pit</td>
                                <td>area terrain</td>
                                <td>volume Prismatoid</td>
                                <td>volume backf.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{excSloped.areaExPit}}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4">
                        <h4>excavation vertical</h4>
                        <table class="bordered striped calculations-table" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>area excavation pit</td>
                                <td>area terrain</td>
                                <td>volume Prismatoid</td>
                                <td>volume backf.</td>
                                <td>wall area</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td> 
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
        {{/with}}
    </div>   
</template>
```

Comment: Show your `calculationsData` helper code as well

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation on [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html). You must use `this.workingSpace.get()` / `this.workingSpace.set(someValue)` methods to access the value of the property. Doing `(this.length + 2*this.workingSpace)` won't work as intended, you're actually trying to multiply the ReactiveVar object by 2.

Using ReactiveVar isn't necessary unless I'm missing some context. If the values of these properties can change and you want the UI to update when these changes happen, keep them as ReactiveVars. Otherwise, just use template scoped variables. In the onCreated/onRendered methods `this.someVariable` allows you to access the variable through `Template.instance().someVariable` in a helper method and through the templateInstance parameter passed into event handlers.

Look into the documentation on [Helper Methods](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-helpers). You've defined the functions `excSloped()` and `excVertical()` on the template object, these should be setup as helper methods. Using helper methods with the get method of the ReactiveVar will make you're UI update reactively but they can also be used to serve static data.

```
Template.smartoptimizer.helpers({
 excSloped() {
  // code here
 },
 excVertical() {
  // code here
 }
});
```